# How can I adjust subtitles in Totem?

Tags: totem, subtitle

How do I adjust subtitles in Totem player so that I can forward or delay it?

Comment: This is my question, too! In VLC, the keys `H` and `J` are specified for solving delay in subtitles; How it can be done in default player of Gnome?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this feature is not included in Totem movie player (yet), so just play with VLC, and adjust your subtitles with the <kbd>H</kbd> and <kbd>J</kbd> buttons.

You can set VLC as the default movie player by clicking the gear button on the top right, select *About computer*, then click *Default Application* and change *Videos* with *VLC*.